# ionic - $state.go with params issue1

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I just create the ionic project and I'm trying to make the sign in and sign up page and I just implement the HTML and CSS. but the problem is I can't change position between controllers.

The URL of controller is changes but the page is not changed. I was trying to import the correct module but I can't find the method.

Comment: Could you please share some lines ode code?

Comment: Since the above was not edited and improved as requested, another downvote, with regret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in app.js, your templateURL , url is properly defined.

Most of the time it might be your 'URL' problem. 
If you navigated from 'main', your next url should be : /main/success or something like that.

```
.state('tab.main', {
cache: false, //if you want to disable cache in ionic
    url: '/main',
    views: {
        'tab-cases': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```